# Log off when user exits successfully a specific application

Tags: windows-7

I'd like to log off a user from its Windows session when he successfully exits a specific application.
Let's take the following use case:
1. John Doe logs on to its Windows session
2. He opens Windows WordPad text editor (an example of a "specific application") and add some text
3. He saves and exits the application successfully
4. John Doe is automatically logged off from its Windows session

I'd like to find a solution using Windows standard mechanisms.
I have already tried to find a solution using a combination of Local Group Policy, Event Viewer and Task Scheduler. But, I could not trigger the event **for a specific application**.

Here is my (unsuccessful) try:

*Local Group Policy*
1. Open **Local Computer Policy > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy** node
2. Open **Audit process tracking** Properties policy
3. Check **Success** checkbox and click **OK** to validate
4. Execute **GPUpdate /Force** to apply new policy

*Event Viewer*
1. Launch WordPad and exit it successfully (as John Doe would have done it)
2. Look at **Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Security** journal for the event in Windows Event Viewer
3. Once the event is found, right-click on it and select **Attach Task To This Event...**
4. Reach **Action** wizard page, select **Start a program** option and click **Next**
5. Fill-in the field with the following options **Program/script: shutdown** and **Add arguments (optional): /l /f /t 10**

The main problem is that **Event ID: 4689** for a successful **Process Termination** applies to all applications exiting successfully not only to my WordPad process!

Is it possible to trigger on WordPad termination process only?

Comment: This question will get better answers at http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

With 'attach task to this event' the answer is no. However you can have the following script run at logon via logonscript or registry.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{(Security)}\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _    
    ("Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 Where " _
        & "TargetInstance isa 'Win32_Process'")

Do
    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent.TargetInstance
    cmdLine = objEvent.CommandLine
    if InStr(LCase(cmdLine), "wordpad.exe")  then
       wscript.Echo("Wordpad exited. Logging off...")
       Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       WshShell.Run "logoff" 

    end if 

Loop
```